# Why does "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" change inheritance setting of subfolder?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions, file-permissions

For example - suppose I have a FolderA with multiple subfolders and files. Some of these folder/files have inheritance enabled and some have inheritance disabled.

Suppose I do right click on FolderA, checkmark this setting ("Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object checkbox") and click OK; all subfolders/files have their inheritance setting automatically reset to 'Enabled' and inherit the permissions from FolderA even though they were originally set to disable inheritance.

How to ensure that this checkmark doesn't change the inheritance setting or any security settings of subfolders/files that have inheritance disabled?

[image]

Comment: That is literally what this option is supposed to do. Don't enable it if you don't want it.

Comment: But it says "with inheritable permission entries from this object" - So shouldn't it affect only those folder/files that have inheritance enabled?

Comment: No. It says “Replace all child object permission entries”.

Comment: Ok so you mean that even though I have set the child to not inherit - this will force it!